# Overflow:hidden. in js/jquery, compare hidden to visible text

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a overflow:hidden container as below, is there a way for me to figure out via js/jquery what text is visible and what text is hidden?

```
div{
    height:2.4em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    background:pink;   
}

<div>
    I am some text and more text and so on and on I just keep going.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only idea what I have:

```
<div>
    <span>I am some text and more text and so on and on I just keep going.</span>
</div>
```

And remove letters until span is bigger than div :P (you cane use `element.offsetHeight` and  `element.offsetWidth` or `$(element).height` and `$(element).width`)

Answer (score 0):

The tricky parts are finding out how much fits in on a word basis, considering wrapping and the line-height. Wrote a small jquery plugin. Here is the snippet,

```
$.fn.visibleText = function () {
    // Get the currents
    var currWidth = this.width();
    var currHeight = this.height();
    var htmlContent = this.html();


    var lineHeight = parseFloat(this.css("lineHeight"), 10);
    // Need to calculate the number of lines visible
    // as currHeight < numLines * lineHeight, at times
    // Eg: Try changing height to 4.4em and width to 110px
    var numLines = Math.round(currHeight / lineHeight);
    var actualHeight = (numLines * lineHeight);

    // Clearing
    this.html("");
    this.height("initial");

    // Push to HTML until hitting the terminating conditions
    // currWordLength is required since wrapping of a word could push
    // to the line
    var vContent = "",
        currWordLength = 0;
    while (this.height() <= actualHeight) {
        var currChar = htmlContent[vContent.length];
        vContent += currChar;
        this.html(vContent);
        if (currChar === " ") {
            currWordLength = 0;
        }
        currWordLength++;
        if (htmlContent.length === vContent.length) {
            currWordLength = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    var visible = vContent.substring(0, vContent.length - currWordLength);

    // Revert to originals
    this.height(currHeight);
    this.html(htmlContent);
    return {
        visible: visible,
        hidden: htmlContent.substring(visible.length, htmlContent.length)
    }
};
```

Fiddle it at http://jsfiddle.net/aravindbaskaran/v2ECm/